# Display previous images stored in an array

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a gallery that will open a modal when you click on an image or video. I am now trying to implement a previous and next button. I've been unable to get it working completely, I can only get it to display ONLY the previous image/video that the user initially clicked. I cannot get it to continually display the previous or after images/videos.

I feel like some sort of loop could do the trick, but I personally couldn't figure out the condition of a loop in order for it to loop properly.

Here is a https://jsfiddle.net/Boros/r9nsyw0m/

If you click on any image or video itself(not the play button), then click the previous arrow, you will see it displays the correct previous image/video. However, if you try to press the previous button again, nothing happens. Another issue is the next button doesn't even work. I have no idea why since it should be the exact same code as the previous button except it just adds one to the index instead of subtracting one like the previous button code. You may need to refresh after closing the modal after you clicked the previous button since it will display the incorrect image/video if you re-open the modal.

Line 50: Previous button

```
$("#previous").addEventListener("click", evt => {
     slides[g].style.display = "none";
     slides[g - 1].style.display = "initial";
});
```

Line 55: Next button

```
$("#next").addEventListener("click", evt => {
     slides[g].style.display = "none";
     slides[g + 1].style.display = "initial";
});
```

I've been learning JS for a couple months now so the code might be all over the place but I am happy I was able to get this far on this project.

Comment: jsFiddle warns you that the ID `video_container` must be unique. You are declaring the function `closeModal` inside a loop - more than once. There is a large amount of code there to go through.... too much perhaps

Comment: Does this help https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp ?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius thanks for pointing that out. I should have been using a class instead of an id. I have decided to re-write my project and I managed to optimize it quite a bit. I have now only declared the closeModal function once as global so it can be called anywhere else depending on how the user opened the modal. It seems adding previous & next functionality is a bit out of my league currently. I will just keep studying until I'm able to implement it, unless someone manages to help me with it. here is the updated https://jsfiddle.net/Boros/5th0rk3a/7/ it currently lacks documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a little look at the newer version of the code and whilst it is better it still has issues - the main being that the navigation still does not work. There appears to be a lot of repetition within the various parts of the code and I ended up approaching from a different direction to achieve what I hope was the stated goal. I may not have implemented all the things I see in the original - such as removing the `tabindex` attributes or other such. I also could not understand why there is duplication of the images/videos on the page other than to provide content for the modal - so these items were removed explicitly from the modal so that they can be copied/cloned later when actually needed.

```js
(function(){
  'use strict';

  let index;
  const d=document;
  const q=(e,n=d)=>n.querySelector(e);
  const qa=(e,n=d)=>n.querySelectorAll(e);


  const col=qa('#gallery img,#gallery video');
  const _length=col.length-1;
  const modal=q('#my_modal');
  const receiver=q('.receiver',modal);
  
  const setdisplay=(n,s)=>n.style.display=s;
  const setoverflow=(n,s)=>n.style.overflow=s;
  const setindex=(i)=>qa('[data-type="nav"]').forEach(n=>n.dataset.index=i);
  const pausevideos=()=>qa('video').forEach(n=>n.pause());
  const clearstyle=(c)=>qa('[data-type="nav"]').forEach(n=>n.classList.remove(c));
  const warn=(e,a,b,c)=>{
    clearstyle(c);
    if( a==b )e.target.classList.add(c)
  };
  const setinitialstate=(i,c)=>{
    clearstyle(c);
    if( i==0 )q('[data-task="prev"]').classList.add(c)
    if( i==_length )q('[data-task="next"]').classList.add(c)
  }
  const _CN='red';



  /*
    Define all the event handlers for 
    the modal buttons etc
  */
  const closeclickhandler=(e)=>{
    receiver.innerHTML='';
    pausevideos();
    setdisplay(modal,'none');
    setoverflow(d.body,'initial');
    return true;
  };

  /*

    The prev/next handlers could be a single function
    that processes the dataset to fork the logic within.

    Find the index from the button and use that to determine
    and display the next/prev item. The `setcontent` function
    takes the item and clones it so it can be displayed.

  */
  const previousclickhandler=(e)=>{
    index=e.target.dataset.index;
    if( index > 0 ){
      index--;
      warn(e,index,0,_CN);
      setindex(index);
      setcontent(col[index]);
    }
    return true;
  };

  const nextclickhandler=(e)=>{
    index=e.target.dataset.index;
    if( index < _length){
      index++;
      warn(e,index,_length,_CN);
      setindex(index);
      setcontent(col[index])
    }
    return true;
  };

  const bttnclickhandler=(e)=>{
    /*
      This is a `delegated` event handler
      bound to the modal but operating
      only on elements with a data-task
      attribute.
    */
    switch( e.target.dataset.task ){
      case 'close': return closeclickhandler(e);
      case 'prev':  return previousclickhandler(e);
      case 'next':  return nextclickhandler(e);
    }
  };

  /*
    assign initial slide to the modal and
    then set the index to the navigation 
    buttons.
  */
  const slideclickhandler=(e)=>{
    setcontent(e.target);
    setindex(e.target.dataset.index);
    setinitialstate(e.target.dataset.index,_CN);
  };

  const keyuphandler=(e)=>{
    /* close modal if the user presses the ESC/Enter key */
    if( e.keyCode == 27 || e.keyCode == 13 )closeclickhandler.call(this,e);
  };

  const setcontent=(item)=>{
    let clone=item.cloneNode(true);
    let div=d.createElement('div');
      div.className=clone instanceof HTMLImageElement ? 'img_slides' : 'video_slides';
      div.append( clone );

    if( clone instanceof HTMLVideoElement ){
      div.append( item.nextElementSibling.cloneNode( true ) );
      clone.controls=true;
      clone.muted=true;
    }

    receiver.innerHTML='';
    receiver.appendChild( div );
    setdisplay(div,'initial');
    setdisplay(modal,'initial');
  };










  /*
    Assign all the listeners
  */
  col.forEach((n,i)=>{
    n.dataset.index=i;  //  !!important!!
    n.setAttribute( 'alt', n.src.split('/').pop() );
    n.addEventListener('click',slideclickhandler);
  });
  modal.addEventListener('click',bttnclickhandler);
  d.addEventListener('keyup',keyuphandler);
})();
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: black;
}
#gallery {
  text-align: center;
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select:none; 
  user-select:none;
}
#gallery img, video {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 360px;
  height: 480px;
  object-fit: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;  
}
.video_container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 360px;
  height: 480px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Prevents video from moving when hovered on chrome */
.video_container video {
  filter: brightness(1);
}
.fa-play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 9999;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
}
#gallery img:hover, .video_container:hover {
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.fa-play:hover {
  transition: color 0.5s;
  color: #181818;
}





@keyframes fadeIn {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to { opacity: 0; }
}
#my_modal {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select:none; 
  user-select:none;
}
.img_slides, 
.video_slides {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.img_slides img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  object-fit: contain;
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
}
.video_slides video{
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  object-fit: contain;
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
}
#close_button,
[data-task='close']{
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;

  border-radius: 16px;
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select:none; 
  user-select:none;
}
#previous,
[data-task='prev']{
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
  width: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select:none; 
  user-select:none;
}
#next,
[data-task='next']{
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
  width: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select:none; 
  user-select:none;
}
#close_button:hover,
[data-task='close']:hover{
  transition: opacity 0.1s;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#previous:hover,
[data-task='prev']:hover{
  transition: opacity 0.1s;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#next:hover,
[data-task='next']:hover{
  transition: opacity 0.1s;
  opacity: 0.5;
}




/* new */
.receiver{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.receiver img,
.receiver video{
  margin:auto
}
.red{
  color:red;
}
[data-char]:after{
  content:attr(data-char)
}
```

```html
<div id='gallery'>
  <img src='//i.imgur.com/gyVTo26.jpg' alt='' tabindex='1' />
  <img src='//i.imgur.com/bEo04qh.jpg' alt='' tabindex='1' />
  <img src='//i.imgur.com/iRENtzp.jpg' alt='' tabindex='1' />
  <img src='//i.imgur.com/ElkQu54.jpg' alt='' tabindex='1' />
  <img src='//i.imgur.com/Aj25iuv.jpg' alt='' tabindex='1' />

  <div class='video_container'>
    <video src='//i.imgur.com/kKGF9Az.mp4' tabindex='1' muted></video>
    <i class='fas fa-play'></i>
  </div>
  <div class='video_container'>
    <video src='//i.imgur.com/p7ohLnA.mp4' tabindex='1' muted></video>
    <i class='fas fa-play'></i>
  </div>

  <img src='//i.imgur.com/PxWajo9.jpg' alt='' tabindex='1' />
  <img src='//i.imgur.com/CAh7F8p.jpg' alt='' tabindex='1' />
</div>




<div id='my_modal'>
  <div class='receiver'></div>
  <span data-task='close' data-char='&times;' tabindex='0'></span>
  <span data-task='prev' data-char='&lt;' data-type='nav' tabindex='0'></span>
  <span data-task='next' data-char='&gt;' data-type='nav' tabindex='0'></span>
</div>
```

---

**Update**
Following from your comments regarding beginner status and still learning I worked a similar solution to that I proposed before but without the `cloneNode` approach and without modifying your HTML structure at all (apart from removing the scheme from image/video urls )

```js
"use strict";
let index;

const d=document;
const body=d.body;
const q=(e,n=d)=>n.querySelector(e);
const qa=(e,n=d)=>n.querySelectorAll(e);

let modal=q('#my_modal');
let gallery=q('#gallery');
let bttns=qa('span',modal);
let videos=qa('video');
let collection=qa('[tabindex="1"]',gallery);

let items=qa('div[ class$="_slides" ]',modal);
let _length=items.length - 1;


const setdisplay=(nodes,style)=>{
  if( nodes instanceof Array || nodes instanceof NodeList )nodes.forEach(n=>n.style.display=style);
  else if( nodes instanceof HTMLElement )nodes.style.display=style;
};
const setoverflow=(n,value)=>n.style.overflow=value;
const setattribs=(col,attr,value)=>col.forEach(n=>n.setAttribute(attr,value));
const pausevideos=(col)=>col.forEach(n=>n.pause());
const removetabs=(col)=>col.forEach(n=>n.removeAttribute('tabindex'));
const setindices=(col,i)=>col.forEach(n=>n.dataset.index=i);

const closeModal = e => {
  if ( e.target == q('#close_button') || e.keyCode==27 || e.keyCode==13 ) {
    setoverflow(body,'initial')
    setdisplay(modal,'none');
    setdisplay(items,'none');
    setattribs(collection,'tabindex',1);
    pausevideos(videos);
  }
};

const bttnclickhandler=(e)=>{
  switch(e.target.id){
    case 'previous':
      if( index > 0 )index--;
    break;
    case 'next':
      if( index < _length )index++;
    break;
  }
  setindices(bttns,index);
  setdisplay(items,'none');
  setdisplay(items[index],'initial');
  return true;
}


// set the dataset attribute on all items within modal & gallery
qa('#gallery > *').forEach((n,i)=>n.dataset.index=i);
qa('#my_modal > *').forEach((n,i)=>n.dataset.index=i);


// assign event listener to each item in the gallery which displays 
// that item & sets the global index.
qa('img,div',gallery).forEach( n=>n.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  // Find which index the clicked item has and set the global index variable
  index=Number( this.dataset.index );

  // Find the respective item from the modal collection of nodes
  let item=items[index];

  // set properties
  setdisplay(modal,'initial');
  setdisplay(item,'initial');
  setindices(bttns,index);
  removetabs(collection);
}));


bttns.forEach(bttn=>bttn.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  switch( e.target.id ){
    case 'close_button':return closeModal(e);
    default: return bttnclickhandler(e);
  }
}));

d.addEventListener( 'keyup', closeModal );
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: black;
}
#gallery {
  text-align: center;
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select:none; 
  user-select:none;
}
#gallery img, video {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 360px;
  height: 480px;
  object-fit: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;  
}
.video_container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 360px;
  height: 480px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Prevents video from moving when hovered on chrome */
.video_container video {
  filter: brightness(1);
}
.fa-play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 9999;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
}
#gallery img:hover, .video_container:hover {
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.fa-play:hover {
  transition: color 0.5s;
  color: #181818;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to { opacity: 0; }
}
#my_modal {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select:none; 
  user-select:none;
}
.img_slides, .video_slides {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.img_slides img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  object-fit: contain;
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
}
.video_slides video{
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  object-fit: contain;
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
}
#close_button {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;

  border-radius: 16px;
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select:none; 
  user-select:none;
}
#previous {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
  width: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select:none; 
  user-select:none;
}
#next {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
  width: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -moz-user-select: none; 
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -ms-user-select:none; 
  user-select:none;
}
#close_button:hover {
  transition: opacity 0.1s;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#previous:hover {
  transition: opacity 0.1s;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
#next:hover {
  transition: opacity 0.1s;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/gyVTo26.jpg" alt="" tabindex="1">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/bEo04qh.jpg" alt="" tabindex="1">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/iRENtzp.jpg" alt="" tabindex="1">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/ElkQu54.jpg" alt="" tabindex="1">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/Aj25iuv.jpg" alt="" tabindex="1">
  <div class="video_container">
    <video src="//i.imgur.com/kKGF9Az.mp4" tabindex="1" muted></video>
    <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="video_container">
    <video src="//i.imgur.com/p7ohLnA.mp4" tabindex="1" muted></video>
    <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
  </div>
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/PxWajo9.jpg" alt="" tabindex="1">
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/CAh7F8p.jpg" alt="" tabindex="1">
</div>

<div id="my_modal">
  <div class="img_slides">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/gyVTo26.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img_slides">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/bEo04qh.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img_slides">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/iRENtzp.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img_slides">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/ElkQu54.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img_slides">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/Aj25iuv.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="video_slides">
    <video src="//i.imgur.com/kKGF9Az.mp4" controls muted></video>
  </div>
  <div class="video_slides">
    <video src="//i.imgur.com/p7ohLnA.mp4" controls muted></video>
  </div>
  <div class="img_slides">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/PxWajo9.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="img_slides">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/CAh7F8p.jpg" alt="">
  </div>



  <span id="close_button" tabindex="0">&times;</span>
  <span id="previous" tabindex="0">&lt;</span>
  <span id="next" tabindex="0">&gt;</span>
</div>
```

The idea remains the same in principal. Items within the `gallery` and items within the `modal` are assigned a `data-index` attribute when the page loads ( this could be done another way but this is, imo, easier & less cluttered )

The global `index` variable is changed according to whether the `previous` or `next` buttons is clicked and that new `index` value is used to select the item within the `modal` with that same `data-index` value. The buttons `data-index` attribute is changed to that new `index` value so that the next time a button is clicked the process can repeat. If the `index` is approaching the limits ( 0 or _length ) then the `index` remains unchanged so no error occurs trying to select an invalid index. Alternatively at that point the `index` could be reset to the opposite value perhaps so the process becomes cyclic - not tested though. Plus 1?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is definitely what I would like to accomplish & definitely answers my question. However, since I am still new to JS, this answer is a bit too much for me to understand. I see syntax in your answer that I am unfamiliar with. I am learning from a book so I've still yet to reach the page where "cloneNode" is explained. I have since took your input and managed to optimize my code a lot more. Whenever I learn how to clone images and videos when needed, I will remove the HTML of the modal. Currently I will focus on optimizing what I know and implement new things as I go.

Comment: I will keep looking back at your code as I learn new things in order to understand it more, and how I could implement it into mine. here is the new optimized code https://jsfiddle.net/Boros/1s69hjo7/2/